# SQL server : Login issue while querying

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, authentication

I have a web application running with a SQL server 2005 DB as back end.I took the db back of the production site and restored in my development machine.Then i tried to query this database using the login "sa".When trying to execute the "**select * from Customers**" query, i am getting a message like "**Invalid object name 'Customers**"
But when i run "**SELECT * FROM [352974_mg4l1].[Customers]**", It is returning records.
352974_mg4l1 is a user for this database present when i restored the db backup from production.
What i have to do for getting the records using with simple select query which i used initially("**select * from Customers**" ). I know it is something related to login issue.Can any one tell me how to solve this ?

Answer (score 2):

The Customers database object is not owned by the dbo schema.

And by referencing Customers as 'sa' you are looking for [dbo].[Customers] ?

I would suggest to:

- either provide the object's full name
- either change it's schema

Edit:

To alter the schema of said table try this:

```
ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER [352974_mg4l1].Customers;
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173423.aspx

Comment: How to change the schema ? where to ?

Comment: Is Changing schema for each tables reasonable ?

Comment: Well if you're using the database for tests during development sure.

Answer (score 0):

Look up sp_changeobjectowner in Books on line. That will help you change the owner. The real question is how the object got created to a specific owner to begin with. If this is true on prod, you could have some major issues with other people accesssing the database.

Comment: When using integrated security newly created database objects are bound to the current user

Comment: I always specify dbo in my creation scripts